# Reuse Android HttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient

Is it ok to use the same **HttpClient** **object** for several execute method calls? 
(assuming I'm not executing the **HttpGet requests** simultaneously)

Comment: http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2009/08/http-connection-reuse-in-android.html

Comment: @Ajay: Your link is alive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AndroidHttpClient` to do that with api 8 or above. See this link to know how to work with AndroidHttpClient: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/CreateHttpconnection.htm

Otherwise, you can use `ThreadSafeClientConnManager`. "This connection manager doesn’t handle a single connection, but a pool of them, where each connection can be taken from the pool, allocated to a thread (which then has exclusive access to it), and returned to the pool once the thread yields it. If the same or another thread claims a connection for the same route, then a connection can be immediately reused from the pool  without the need to first close and reopen it, thereby avoiding the overhead of the handshake performed by HTTP when establishing a new connection.ThreadSafeClientConnManager  for instance sets the default values for the maximum  number of total connections to 20, and the maximum number of connections per route to 2."
         - from "Android in Practice"

You can see this link to know about ThreadSafeClientConnManager: http://massapi.com/class/th/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to use same HttpClient, but you can use AndroidHttpClient,

```
AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("xxxx");
```

AndroidHttpClient is thread safe.